# Transparently saving data in HTML5 Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I would like to use Javascript object literals and arrays normally and have them **automatically** saved in local storage.

I would like to read, edit and delete members of the object literals and arrays as I would with any other object - using normal assignment operator `a.b = 'c'` for assigning values and normal dot-notation expressions `d.e` for reading.

When browser next time visits the page, the previous contents of these arrays and object literals would be automatically loaded from the local storage. I wish not to explicitly call anything to store this data, it should just work.

What are my options?

Comment: I don't think you have any options since the data would have to be serialised in some form.
You could however change your object properties to be methods which perform the saving

Comment: @DJL don't you think my option would be to use a library that would handle the serialization transparently in the background?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such library. That's not to say that one doesn't exist.

One option you might consider is using a timer to read and seralise the data. I wouldn't like this option much though.

Answer (score 0):

example using methods instead of vanilla properties

```
var SavedObject= { 
  b: function(val) { 
    if (typeof(val)!=="undefined") {
      this._b=val;
      this.SerialiseToLocalStorage();
    }
    return val;
  },SerialiseToLocalStorage: function() {
    //whatever
  }
}

SavedObject.b(1); //set value
var x = SaveObject.b(); // get value
```

You'll also need to initalise the values on document load of course...